# Upload file and get url prefilled in a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I have a form where users upload files (images), the file is uploaded once they select the file, what I'm trying to do is to get the url of the uploaded file and prefill it in the next text input value. Also to be able to rename the uploaded file from the first input(filename)

Here is the upload php script:

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 /* Get the name of the uploaded file */
 $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

 /* Choose where to save the uploaded file */
 $location = "uploads/".$filename;

 /* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
 if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) { 
 echo 'Success';
 
 } else { 
 echo 'Failure'; 
 }

?>
```

and here is the form script

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>upload</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    
    <script>
    async function uploadFile() {
        let formData = new FormData();           
        formData.append("file", fileupload.files[0]);
        await fetch('assets/php/upload.php', {
            method: "POST", 
            body: formData
        });    
        alert("url location");
    }
    </script>
        <label>File Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="filename"><br>
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" onchange="uploadFile()"/><br>
        <input type="text" value="url of the uploaded file"/>

    
    
    
    <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>
```

More information about the problem: The result will be two forms, one will upload the file to local server and return the url to the second form and the second form will send the information to a google form to be submitted, it's a workaround as users can't upload directly to google forms without having to login, this is the actual problem that I can't find a solution for, so I'm trying to do this as a workaround to uploading the file directly to google forms

Thanks you so much for your help

Comment: "I want" isn't a question and doesn't describe a problem. We can help if necessary where there's a specific issue, but this is not a free write-my-code service...you're expected to show some effort to solve it yourself first, or at least narrow down the issue for us. Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck exactly? What is preventing you from achieving what you need? Are there any other issues happening in the code you've shown, or does all that work smoothly currently? See also [ask] - you haven't actually asked us a question yet!

Comment: P.S. Out of curiosity... `prefill it in the next text input value`...why would you need to put something in a text input, which the server already knows about? Surely it's enough to just display it? Am I missing something there? Inputs are for input data, not output.

Comment: Are you trying to turn the file into a URL, or if you download the file from a URL you can upload it to the site and it will return the URL? If you're trying to turn the file into a URL, using a JavaScript FileReader, you can but I'm unsure of a way to do it in PHP. For getting where you downloaded the file from, I could be wrong but I don't think any image formats store where a file was downloaded from.

Comment: @Someguy I think they mean they want to return the URL of the file's location on the server once PHP has saved it to a permanent location. Nothing to do with filereader. It's unclear why they don't just echo the $location variable (probably prepended with the base URL of the site) - OP hasn't actually explained the problem they're having.

Comment: `one form is to upload files and the second one will get the file url and submit it to the second form`...why? Where does the second form send that data to? The only reason I can think of for splitting it like this would be if the second form sends the data to somewhere outside your PHP application (e.g. another API or something). Otherwise, you should just save the location directly in your first PHP script to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: Exactly it's two forms, one will upload the file to local server and return the url to the second form and the second form will send the information to a google form to be submitted, it's a workaround as users can't upload directly to google forms without having to login, this is the actual problem that I can't find a solution for, so I'm trying to do this as a workaround to uploading the file directly to google forms

Comment: You can interact with the google API in your PHP backend by using a service account, without needing user interaction. That could be one solution, depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: I tried that but google forms didn't get the url, this is why I was trying to catch the url from one form and pass it to other form

Comment: Well it's unclear what problem you had or what you did which caused that, or why this would be the workaround. You seem unsure how to get the URL and send it _anywhere_, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: So there is no way to get the uploaded file url and display it? I tried to look everywhere and couldn't find a fix for that

Comment: of course there is. You already have the `$location` variable containing the path where you saved the file. I'd guess you probably just need to prepend the base URL onto that (unless your files are not stored in a HTTP-accessible location, or you have some sort of routing engine in place). As I said at the beginning though, it's unclear what you've tried, or what problem you had.

Comment: the files are http accessible, I tried to pass the $location to form but I got undefined value

Comment: Where and how did you do that? Given that you're making a fetch() request to upload the file, anything you echo from PHP will come back to the fetch request in a Javascript variable, for you to use. But in your question you showed no JS code which attempts to read the response from that fetch() or do anything with it.

Comment: I just updated the post , I didn't add it originally because it didn't work, it returned the upload.html file url, I did echo location $location but it didn't work

Comment: I also tried <script>
  var url = <?php echo(json_encode($location)); ?>;
  </script> but that didn't work either

Comment: You need to find some examples online of how to read the response from a fetch() request, because you don't seem to know the basics of how to use it

Comment: can you point me to where to look because I've been looking for days and I still can't find an answer

Comment: @Frontlinemedical is this for an actual company? the other problem here is that literally anyone can install a backdoor on your server given the code written as is, access your files, probably your databases, and turn it into spam farm. you might want to hire out for this stuff. if you don't understand what you are doing, it could put your company in jeopardy.

Comment: `looking for days` ...Where have you been looking? Did you try the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch ? Alternatively:  https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-fetch-api/ . More widely: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+response+from+fetch ...there is no shortage of examples.

Comment: `none of it helped`....how so? Literally `if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) { echo $location;` in PHP and `var result = await fetch('assets/php/upload.php', { method: "POST", body: formData });  alert(result);` in JS. There's examples right there in dozens of places showing you how to assign the response to a variable from the await fetch....it's not that we don't want to answer, it's that it should be really really obvious from all the many examples of that exact thing online with no need to spend time to repeat it again! You're encouraged to be self-sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for the assist I figured it out.

here's the answer in case someone else is looking

upload.php file

```
    <?php

/* Get the name of the uploaded file */
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ipad = rand(1256252, 25665588665);;
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' .$ipad . '.' .$filename;

$location = "uploads/".$newfilename;

/* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) {  
  echo $location;

} else { 
  echo 'Failure'; 
}

?>
```

and here is the js script:

```
<script>
    async function uploadFile() {
        let formData = new FormData(); 
        
        formData.append("file", fileupload.files[0]);
        var response = await fetch('assets/php/upload.php', {
            method: "POST", 
            body: formData
        });    
        let data = "localhost/assets/php/" + await response.text()

        console.log(data);
        outputfile.value = data
        }

    </script>
    
       
        <input id="fileupload" type="file"  class="upload" name="fileupload" value="new" onchange="uploadFile()"/>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id='outputfile'/>
```

Although I wasn't able to change the file name from the text input, but I created a random name instead